# Is there a more efficient way to generate a distance matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance

I was wondering if there is a more straight forward, more efficient way of generating a distance matrix given the H x W of the matrix, and the starting index location.

For simplicity lets take a 3x3 matrix where the starting point is (0,0).  Thus, the distance matrix to be generated is:

```
[[ 0.          1.          2.        ]
 [ 1.          1.41421356  2.23606798]
 [ 2.          2.23606798  2.82842712]]
```

Index (0,1) is 1 distance away, while index (2,2) is 2.828 distance away.

The code I have so far is below:

```
def get_distances(start, height, width):
        matrix = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float16)
        indexes = [(y, x) for y, row in enumerate(matrix) for x, val in enumerate(row)]
        to_points = np.array(indexes)
        start_point = np.array(start)
        distances = np.linalg.norm(to_points - start_point, ord=2, axis=1.)

    return distances.reshape((height, width))



height = 3
width = 3
start = [0,0]
distance_matrix = get_distances(start, height, width)
```

This is pretty efficient already, I think. But numpy always surprise me with some tricks that I usually never think of, so I was wondering if there exist one in this scenario.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hypot()` and broadcast:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(3)
np.hypot(x[None, :], x[:, None])
```

or the `outer` method:

```
np.hypot.outer(x, x)
```

the result:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.41421356,  2.23606798],
       [ 2.        ,  2.23606798,  2.82842712]])
```

to calculate the distance between every point on a grid to a fixed point `(x, y)`:

```
x, y = np.ogrid[0:3, 0:3]
np.hypot(x - 2, y - 2)
```

Comment: This is interesting.  But if I want the starting point say from (2,2), how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @user1179317 do you want to calculate the distance between every point on a grid to a fixed point `(x, y)`?

Comment: Yup, from a start point to every single index/point in the matrix